# how to search data using joins when tables have no foreign keys directly involved

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

i want to find the building and room_number which used by a computer sci department. (Use inner join) from this following Design because the tables are not directly linked.

classroom table

```
Building   Room_number  Capacity
Packard          101    500
Painter          514    10
Taylor           3128   70
Watson           100    30
Watson           120    50
```

department table

```
  dept_name   building  budget
  Biology       Watson  90000.00
  Comp. Sci.    Taylor  100000.00
  Elec. Eng.    Taylor  85000.00
  Finance      Painter  120000.00
  History      Painter  50000.00
  Music        Packard  80000.00
  Physics       Watson  70000.00
```

what i tried

```
SELECT classroom.room_number, classroom.building
FROM classroom
INNER JOIN department
ON 
 department.building=classroom.building
```

1) How can i get data using join from two tables when they are not linked directly but have 4,5 tables between them. i have also attached my database design 
any kind of help guidance will be highly appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHIer.png)

Comment: `SELECT classroom.room_number, classroom.building FROM classroom, department WHERE department.building=classroom.building` (additionaly : `group by classroom.room_number, classroom.building` may be needed)

Comment: it doesn't work as i said i have to use inner join and both the tables don't have foreign keys

Comment: It is inner join but other syntax... you don't need foreign keys for that... How exactly doesn't it work?

Comment: no it  shows me all the values. it doesn't exactly show the room and building that that is used by computer science students

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? mysql <> sql server. And if you really want some help you need to provide some details about what you want. What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Okay first I would say the database design is not good.

Second this should be your query:

```
SELECT cr.building, cr.room_number FROM department d
LEFT JOIN course c ON d.dept_name = c.dept_name
LEFT JOIN section s ON c.course_id = s.course_id
LEFT JOIN classroom cr ON s.building = cr.building AND s.room_number = cr.room_number
WHERE d.dept_name LIKE '%Comp. Sci.%';
```

Third the picture that you uploaded is really really bad quality!

Now about the design - you should put a link between **department** and **classroom** because this will total ease the way you pull data, because you could have buildings with same names for different departments.

**Query explanation**

1. Starting from `WHERE` - show only departments with name like Comp. Sci.(we should always rely on this name, you should think about putting **ID** column)
2. Now first `LEFT JOIN` will get all the courses from department Comp. Sci.
3. Second `LEFT JOIN` will get all sections that Comp. Sci. courses use
4. Third `LEFT JOIN` will give you all class rooms from Comp. Sci. department's sections

Too many joins to get this data. Just put a link between those two tables and think about putting **IDs**

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have ambiguity issue here in column `Building` of table `Classroom`. You need another table with name `Builing` add buildings in that table.

then match these three tables using inner join to return the required data.
Good luck!..